# Equivalent of QTikZ for PSTricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have recently seen the very useful QTikZ program for interactive viewing of TikZ diagrams. I was wondering if a similar program exists for drawing PSTricks diagrams.

Comment: I think you can directly use pstricks in QTikz, just add the right packages and it should work with no problem. If you want some syntax highlighting and add standard pstricks commands in the menus, it should not be too difficult to hack QTikZ (its OpenSource).

Comment: Have a look at PSTricks assistant [Pstplus Gui in fr](http://www.xm1math.net/pstplus/index.html)

Comment: @Heidar I want adding pstricks command in the menu and command completion/suggestion with pstricks command. Unfortunately I have no experience with hacking or programming, I am just a simple end user!

Comment: may be with `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}` and a preamble template supporting [LaTeX editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717), there is no need for separate PSTricks editor.

Comment: @Per I see. If you don't find any good alternative, I would suggest you email the developers of QTikZ and see whether they are interested in making a Qpstricks. I think it can be done with very small changes of the code. And many people might find it very useful.

Answer (score 5):

it should be no problem to modify or copy a template like the ones in `/usr/share/qtikz/templates/`

```
 % PGF style template to be used in the ktikz program
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{mdbch}{\skewchar\font=48}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdbch}{m}{n}{<->s*[0.96] mdbchr7y}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdbch}{m}{it}{<->ssub * mdbch/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdbch}{b}{n}{<->s*[0.96] mdbchb7y}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{mdbch}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * mdbch/b/n}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}
\begin{document}
<>
\end{document}
```

Instead of `tikz` use `pstricks-add` and `pspicture`. 
And instead of `preview` load `auto-pst-pdf`. In the configuration of QtikZ extend the `pdflatex` call to `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

Then it should also work because it only uses package `preview`.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, but I would like to use some tool like qtikz to practice and learn PStricks. Qtiks is a great tool for learning Tikz. When I start typing a command it offers the right syntax and different variations of it, and after I enter the command, I can see the result. Also in the left side window it shows many of the tikz commands with the right syntax. It is an excellent learning tool. Is it possible to modify it to do the same thing with PSTricks command?

Comment: @perting: Sure, this is also possible with PSTricks. You have only to import all available commands for the correct syntax to show. QtikZ is nothing else than an editor which runs automatically the source, if changed. A similiar editor is `Gummi` (http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi)

Comment: @Herbert: I am a windows user, so Gummi is not an option. How can I import PStricks commands to qtikz and in what file these commands should be imported to. I looked in the qtikz folde but did not find an editable text file with tikz commands in it.

Comment: @perting: I suppose it is hardcoded and needs modifieing the source of the program.